# Get from Apache Solr documents where array contains value

Tags: solr

I have a field that is defined:

```
<field name="countries" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

I am looking for query syntax to get from solr documents where field "countries" **contains** value X.

For value X the query that I am looking for should return documents where:

```
countries = ['X','Y',...] or countries = ['X']
```

I already tried tip from this thread [Solr query syntax for array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794418/solr-query-syntax-for-array-field/15806026)

But for `countries: X` it returns only docs where `countries = ['X']` and skips `countries = ['X','Y',...]`

Comment: What is the _actual_ content of your field? As long as you've actually indexed it as a multivalued field, `countries:X` should work just fine. Seems like you've serialized your array as a string, and it's not actually stored as multiple values in Solr.

Comment: Since you are using a string field, make sure the value of X in the array matches case and punctuation (e.g. ['Y','x'] will not match, but ['Y','X'] will match)